# Storing Abbreviations in Vim

Tags: vim

I frequently use `:ab` to save typing time during coding. For e.g. `:ab mat matrix` to replace mat by matrix every time I type mat.

**Is there any way of storing and loading the abbreviations I create for a given file?**
I want something to store my abbreviations as and when I declare them and also reload them when I open a file. I would prefer the abbreviations to be "local" to a file rather than global but I can work around this if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for a single specific file, you could add an autocommand (`:help autocommand` or `:help 40.3`) to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/foobar call FoobarSettings()
function FoobarSettings()
  ab mat matrix
  " ... more setup commands
endfunction
```

Change "foobar" to something that makes more sense for you.

A less flexible clunkier shotgun-style approach is to use sessions (`:help sessions` or `:help 21.4`).  It is unwieldy because sessions by default save a great deal of things including window sizes, open files, options, mappings, folds, etc.  You can change this with the `'sessionoptions'` option if you like.

- After you've created opened the file and set up the abbreviations, `:mksession! sessionfile.vim`.
- To restore the session, from the shell you can do `vim -S sessionfile.vim` or from inside vim you can do `:source sessionfile.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful links:
[Sourcing different .vimrc files](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/vim/example-vim.html.en)
[Different .vimrc for different directories (should work on files too)](http://objectmix.com/editors/148731-%5Bvim%5D-project-specific-vimrc-files.html)